# Synchronize Templates - I've deleted templates, but they're still listed under the "Design" menu

Tags: templates, bug, sync

I have EE configured to save my templates as files.

I had several different template groups that I deleted via FTP. I clicked on "Synchronize Templates" and ticked all the boxes, and hit submit. I no longer see those templates listed under the Synchronize Templates page.

However... **The template groups are still listed under the *Design --> Templates --> Edit* dropdown menu.** There doesn't seem to be any way to get rid of them.

I have a feeling it's because I have Save Revisions turned on. I can see old templates that have clearly been deleted, so opening them up in the EE editor will show an empty file - but with several revisions available to restore.

Is this an ExpressionEngine bug, or is there any way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting them from the Template Manager?